# An animal out of matchsticks

Tags: matches, animals

Ok, I widely failed my two latest matchsticks puzzles, so here's another attempt, part of the [22nd Fortnightly Topic Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5677/fortnightly-topic-challenge-22-animals).

As you can see, you have in front of you eleven matchsticks forming the word *zoo*:

[image]

You have to **move one matchstick**, and **remove one matchstick** to create **a 4-letter word**, which is **the name of an animal**.

You cannot break or stack the matchsticks.

Comment: Nice simple, clear and with a good solution. I think this is an excellent example of how a *good* matchstick-puzzle should look like. +1 from me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Nice one! Here is my solution:

> [image: Solution]

Comment: Drat! Ninja'd while I was hastily making the image.

Comment: Looks like you've moved more than one stick here

Comment: One stick from the last O in zoo has been removed, and another stick from the last O has been moved. The image is turned 90 degrees anticlockwise.

Comment: Completely, didn't see it that way - makes it more impressive :)

Answer (score 10):

I also came to the accepted answer, via a slightly different method.

> Lion
>  [image: Lion puzzle solution]

Comment: П? Like in Russian :-D?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Resembles lower case 'n' too.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Or Greek.

Comment: @randal'thor: Now if we could make a four-letter TA-Π-R or a Π-GGY from the given layout ...

Answer (score 7):

I can get:

> A lion(Reading from right to left and rotating the first matchstick by 90  degrees)

An image:

> [image]

Comment: It could be nice to add an image to your reasoning if you want the tick :)!

Comment: Drat!, hold on a bit...

Comment: Ha, that is what I thought. I was expecting @TheGreatEscaper solution :), because you rotate the *z* and he does not.

Answer (score 2):

Not four letters. Colloquially, at least, this is an animal name:

> cow

An image:

> [image]

Comment: Well, I *precisely* asked for a four letters animal.

Comment: Some do pronounce W as double V. So you have COVV, 4 letters!

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late, but I actually got a different answer than others.

> I got COLT (Baby horse). The L and T are a bit scrunched but I think it's solid.
>
>
>  [image: Colt]